# ERROR TypeError: t.rgb is not a function issue with C3JS in angular prod environment

Tags: angular, production-environment, c3.js

I have done a lot of research to resolve this issue but, didn't find any solution.
I have used c3 js `version 0.7.11` with Angular CLI `version 7.0.7`. can somebody help me into this?

```
main.b5c5d0251120bfab71af.js:1 ERROR TypeError: t.rgb is not a function
    at xe (main.b5c5d0251120bfab71af.js:1)
    at we (main.b5c5d0251120bfab71af.js:1)
    at main.b5c5d0251120bfab71af.js:1
    at Vm (main.b5c5d0251120bfab71af.js:1)
    at Module.UQyC (main.b5c5d0251120bfab71af.js:1)
    at f (runtime.ec2944dd8b20ec099bf3.js:1)
    at new e (main.b5c5d0251120bfab71af.js:1)
    at new r (main.b5c5d0251120bfab71af.js:1)
    at Object.generate (main.b5c5d0251120bfab71af.js:1)
    at t.ngAfterViewInit (main.b5c5d0251120bfab71af.js:1)
```

Comment: Is c3 js version 0.7.11 compatible with angular version 7.0.7?

Comment: @PujanShah Yes it is

Comment: What is the version of @angular-devkit/build-angular?

Comment: @angular-devkit/build-angular:"~0.10.0"

Comment: Change the version of it to 0.803.17 and try once.

Comment: It is Not compatible with @angular/cli:7.0.x and in my case i want to stick to the angular 7

Comment: Try with version ~0.11.0 once

Comment: I checked with multiple versions like 0.11.x, 0.12.x, 0.13.x, but not working for me, i think this issue is not related to @angular-devkit/build-angular or @angular/cli, it may be with C3 JS. @Pujan Shah what do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I got a solution to this problem. It's a problem with the version of D3.
They have released the `4.x.x +`  versions in a [rollupJs](https://rollupjs.org) fashion. which **generate the main D3.js on the fly.** because of these changes it is not getting bundled in main.js file when we give a build with **--prod**.

So, here is the solution to a problem.

step-1: We need to install an updated version of d3. i.e.`5.14.2`.

step-2: Add `./node_modules/d3/dist/d3.js` to the script block under `configuration -> production` 
section. in **angular.json** file.

Here step-2 will build the added file additionally for you.

Comment: I didn't understand step 2, but npm install d3@4.13.0 works like a charm =]

Comment: @ItayBenShmuel Step-2 is just adding the d3.js as an external JS file to be bundled in the build process. but yes as you said d3@4.13.0 works awesome.